# Nucleophile vs base and Electrophile vs acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

How we will figure out that a given compound will behave as nucleophile or base ? Same problem for electrophile and acid.

By the way I have already seen a similar [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/20061/52599) though I didn't find it helpful but if someone could correct the answer posted by Vikas Avasthi then I think (no sure) that it might become part of answer to my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "acid" and "base"? If you're talking about Lewis acid/base theory, then there is no difference. If you're talking about Brønsted acid/base theory, then you need to learn more or gain more experience to identify which is more likely to be operative. It's not that easy to explain in a few sentences.

Comment: I recommend reading the first comment on the question you linked and visiting the link of "SHAB principle".