# Electrophilic base / nucleophilic acid / basic electrophile / acidic nucleophile

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

What I was understanding is that all bases are nucleophiles and acids are electrophiles means the condition for them is same and all nucleophiles are basic and all bases are nucleophiles and same for acid and electrophiles but my sir said that it isn't completely true . Can someone give me an example of electrophilic base / nucleophilic acid / acidic nucleophile / basic electrophile

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/whats-the-difference-between-a-nucleophile-and-a-base

Comment: All these aren't inherent properties of compounds, but are relative  and depend on situation. Some molecule may *act* as nucleophile/base/... While it's a common saying that for example H2SO4 *is* an acid, it's rather that it *usually acts* as one, but it can act also as base. If one says it is an acid it's rather because of  human need for categorization then inherent property.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/whats-the-difference-between-a-nucleophile-and-a-base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ce{HSO4-}$ is acidic ($\mathrm pK_\mathrm a = 1.99$) yet also reacts as a nucleophile e.g. in the acid-catalysed hydration of olefins, which according to my mechanism lecture procedes *via* a sulphate diester intermediate.

If I thought for long enough, I probably could come up with a basic compound that acts as an electrophile in a given situation.

However, having single counterexamples to a general trend isn’t necessarily helpful; it is better to *understand* the differences in terminology. For that, I would like to direct you to [Ben’s answer in the linked question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/20064), that clearly highlights the difference between *nucleophilicity* (a kinetic phenomenon) and *basicity* (a thermodynamic phenomenon).