# Why basicity decreases for leaving groups, but nucleophicity increases for an overall compound, going down the periodic table?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nucleophilicity

Basically, I read that nucleophilicity increases going down the periodic table within a particular group, due to polarizability, but basicity decreases down a group (or family) in the periodic table, because those atoms can stabilize a negative charge, making them good leaving groups. Don't these two points seem to contradict each other, since increasing nucleophilicity should increase basicity?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/whats-the-difference-between-a-nucleophile-and-a-base